# Not loading bootstrap in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have just started using Laravel 8, so how do I include bootstrap in Laravel 8 since my pages are not loading bootstrap?

In this case it does not load the list group with the proper styling.

```php
@extends('layouts. app')

@section('content')
    <h1>{{ $title ?? '' }}</h1>
    
    <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">Web design</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">programming</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">SEO</li>
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Comment: where are you put `bootstrap.css` file ? debug your browser console ..

Comment: Welcome to SO .. `laravel 8` is not come with bootstrap so you need to manually add bootstrap  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/frontend

Comment: i cant find bootstrap.css

Comment: there is no file on frontend scaffolding in the documentation of larave 8 ,i am asuming mix has replaced everything ?

Comment: @waithira mix is not for scaffolding. Two packages exist for scaffolding for Laravel, Laravel UI, and Jetstream. Jetstream doesn't come with Bootstrap out of the box so you'll have to swap the tailwindCss resources for Bootstrap using https://github.com/nascent-africa/jetstrap

Answer (score 7):

For install Bootstrap 4 in Laravel 8 then install following Laravel UI composer package to get command:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

After successfully install above package then we are ready to install Bootstrap.

Exists 2 way to do that, one is a simple Bootstrap setup install and another is install Bootstrap with auth.

Install Bootstrap 4:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

Install Bootstrap 4 with auth

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

Now you can see your resource directory JS folder.

You also need to install npm and run it:

```
npm install
```

and then, run NPM

```
npm run dev
```

Now you can work with your Bootstrap 4 app.

You can use it including these lines on the header of your Blade templates:

```
<head>
   <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
   <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Regards

Answer (score 4):

if you want install bootstrap in laravel 8
install

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

then install bootstrap with auth or not

```
php artisan ui bootstrap (--auth)
```

after that you need to write

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

same steps like laravel 7

all the best

Answer (score 3):

**the easiest way**

remove white space from here `@extends('layouts. app')` to `@extends('layouts.app')`

then put this line in resource\view\layouts\app.blade.php

```
<script src="{{asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js')}}"></script>
```

and put this file in public folder directly [bootstrap](https://mega.nz/file/t3J1wayB#deB_n8v6y4HLO8bmg-gcnFxIfESs2X0lfvgKHla2248)

Answer (score 0):

I ran

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

then

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

then

```
npm install and npm run dev
```

Comment: Laravel 8 is dropping Laravel UI so why not use Laravel Jetstream, I found myself in this exact position last week which led me to create this package: github.com/nascent-africa/jetstrap. It converts the Jetstream tailwindCSS resources to Bootstrap 5 or 4. solves your problem.

Comment: so the new frontend styling is not bootstrap but tailwaind css? i see jetstream is for the authentication scaffolding only ?

Comment: Jetstream isn't just for authentication, it does a little more than that and yes its in tailwindCSS.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8 is dropping bootstrap and implementing tailwind CSS.

I recommend learning and using tailwind css.

This can be easily installed with:

```
npm install

npm install -D tailwindcss

npx tailwindcss init
```

[Laravel Tailwind CSS docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#tailwindcss)

[Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/)

Comment: OP did not ask for an alternative to bootstrap but instructions for bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score -1):

i worked with the older way when you build the website from scratch and that  works, i used bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js and jquery file in public folder of laravel and linked this files to index.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jqueryv3_9_0.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.mini.js') }}" defer></script>
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.mini.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Code is missing in your question