# Why do I need to compile Bootstrap instead of using the CDN in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, sass

I'm a graphic designer who just started learning Laravel this week, recently I've been searching how to install the latest bootstrap version in my project correctly, which is all I need to be honest and I'm not too comfortable with other options like Tailwind.

As some tutorials and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025619/not-loading-bootstrap-in-laravel-8) have suggested I ended up compiling and using a famous project named [laravel/ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui), sadly the resulting version comes with a few changes, that just doesn't look as good in my opinion (different fonts like Nonito, colors and margins)

So now I'm wondering...

- Why is it not recommended to just add the CDN links in my master template?
- Is it possible to update this compiled CSS somehow to make it look as the CDN?

Sorry if this questions might be opinion based, but I'm really out of places to ask, seems like the documentation for Laravel 8.x has removed everything related to Frontend, which are making thing even more confusing for me with all these options Laravel offers.

Comment: You can modify the files in `resources/sass` (fonts/Bootstrap sass variables...) to your liking. Feel free to use the CDN version in your views, but as with every CDN, _should_ the CDN be down/unreachable for some reason you'll get not styles at all.

Comment: you can use cdn links into your master.blade.php or app.blade.php or you can add these links into your app.scss file laravel dnt have restrictions for assets , but if you use vue , react etc then you need to follow asset compiling like npm install and npm run dev or npm run watch but for css you can use cdn links or whatever you want

Comment: The CDN version will just use Bootstrap's defaults. If you're happy with this and you're not worried about the potential (low) risk that the CDN will not be available the just use the CDN. If there are some things that you would like to change then you can always create subsequent styles in your `resources/sass` (don't forgot to compile the styling) and load them after the CDN to override them. If you're going to be making quite a few changes then it would make more sense to include bootstrap locally, make all the edits you want to the config file and go from there.

Comment: Be aware that CDNs have potential privacy implications in places like the EU. It's also easier to customize the non-CDN version with SCSS variables.